# $\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1})$ to power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

EDIT: I just realize that I should start with the derivative of $\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1})$ , and keep going from there.

So $(\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1}))'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, does that mean  this is the same series as $\arctan(x)$?

--

I want to find an expression for $\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1})$ as a power series, with $x_0=0$, for every $x \ne 1$.

My initial thought was to use the known $\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, but I don't know how to keep going if I replace $x$ with $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Really, start with the derivative and simplify it.

Comment: Thank you @IvanNeretin, so it has the same derivative as $\arctan(x)$, is that mean that they share the same series?

Comment: Plug 0 in both $\arctan(x)$ and $\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1})$. You should be able to see the difference.

Comment: @CalculusLover Do not forget that there could be a non-zero constant of integration when returning to the original function.

Comment: @Gary, yes I just figured out that is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the identity $\arctan(\frac{x+1}{x-1}) = - \arctan(\frac{x+1}{1 - x}) = - (\pi/4 + \arctan(x))$

Comment: Wow that is a cool answer!

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)=-\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$
you can express the RHS as a power series, and then integrate the result to get the desired series for your original function $\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for that, the derivative has a $+$ in this case.

Comment: I'd double check that if I were you

Comment: check it again my friend :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+arctan%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x-1%29%29

Answer (score 3):

Let $f\left(x\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right),\;\;\forall |x|<1$ . 
It can be easily showed that:
$$f'\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n}$$
Integrating both sides yields that $\exists  C\in \mathbb R$ such that:
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)+C=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
Check for $f(0)$ to conclude $C$ and you're done.

Comment: Great, exactly what I ended up with. Thanks again!

Comment: Always a pleasure ! :)